# Error: Cannot resolve fragment

Tags: android

I am creating basic material design app according to [google developers codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#3) guide.
I want to add fragment and view pager at step 4. I insert codes into android studio. But errors at these lines:

```
adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "List");
adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "Tile");
adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "Card");
```

Error cannot resolve [List/Tile/Card]ContentFragment()
Any solution for this?

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 0):

This error because you haven't create [List/Tile/Card]ContentFragment().
Look at no.8 at step 4,

> Create 3 Fragment java files. ListContentFragment.java ,
>   TileContentFragment.java and CardContentFragment.java .

those linking to the files. Use them.

Comment: New error when i create them: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.example.android.materialdesigncodelab.TileContentFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' I imported fragment support in all files.